# laravel: how to use multi 'can' in route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

laravel 5:8
I create roles,permissions,permission_role,role_user

And in `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    $permissions = $this->getPermissions();
    if ($permissions) {
        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
                return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
            });
        }
    }
}

protected function getPermissions()
{
    if (\Schema::hasTable('permissions')) {
        return Permission::with('roles')->get();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I try use `can` in route:

```
$can = 'can:manage_global';
Route::get('/create', 'ProductController@create')->middleware($can)->name('panel.product.create');
```

it works.

But how can use multi can?

I try this:

```
$can = 'can:manage_global,manage_articles';
```

but it works only for manage_global not manage_articles.

Answer (score 1):

```
$can = 'can:manage_global|manage_articles';
```

Try this with your desired condition, I applied | (OR) between both permissions conditions